# JSch - Why doesn't CD work?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I've been trying to use JSch, and I made a small GUI.

However, when I tried to use cd work_folder, there will be a exit code 0, which means successful, however, the current directory does not change.

BUT, when I tried ls, pwd, mkdir zzzz, all these commands are executed successfully.

Has anyone has this problem before?

Comment: How are you executing the `cd`, sounds to me like you're doing the equivalent of `ssh user@server cd dir` - this runs the cd then closes the pipe. You need to establish an ssh session. Maybe take a look at sftp.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, First I open the session using user@server, then open a channel("exec") then calling CD blabla. BUT, the channels closes everything when I finish executing an instruction. I think that is supposed to happen?

Comment: Yep, I just had a look at sftp, and the sample code works pretty well, I'm still trying to understand what it's doing though. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @user1157751 Can you please share the solution with us. I'm facing the same issue. Cd is not working.